# Probability distribution of halving a segment

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose you cut a unit segment ("a stick") in half. I'd like to find out *theoretically* the distribution of the length of, say, the left piece based purely on some plausible assumptions, such as symmetry (i.e. the mean is $1/2$ and the distribution is symmetric around it) and that you are never going to completely miss the stick - the length is always positive (i.e. the distribution drops off to $0$ at $0$ and $1$).

I understand that this question might be somewhat open-ended based on what assumptions one considers plausible.

Comment: There does not seem to be a single model that presents itself as the physically most plausible one.

Answer (score 1):

A family of distributions often used to model the breaking of a linear piece is the [beta family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). For every $a\gt0$ and $b\gt0$, the beta $(a,b)$ distribution has density 
$$
\mathrm B(a,b)^{-1}x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\mathbf 1_{0\lt x\lt1}.
$$
Some justifications for this choice come from Bayesian considerations. Several shapes are possible. For shapes dropping to zero at $0$ and $1$, choose $a\gt1$ and $b\gt1$.

Comment: My question is mainly about a derivation, not the result itself. Can you provide a link or outline the derivation? Thanks.

Comment: Derivation of what? Since your question only mentions some partial requirements of the model, fulfilled by many of them, there can be no *derivation*.

Comment: that's what I mean by "open-ended". You can add other plausible requirements. Alternatively, you mention justification from Bayesian considerations. What are they? Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Bayesian_inference